# eliminar ultimos registros de array

Tags: php

Tengo un array con mas de 20 elementos y yo solo deseo los 10 primeros (eliminando apartir del 11 para delante para liberar memoria) existirá alguna forma de lograr esto ?

sustento: tengo una funcion que me separa los productos vendidos generandome este array:

```
$productos = array(2=>20,4=>10,5=>5,5=>1....);
```

y a mi solo me sirven los 10 primeros indices el resto quisiera liberar memoria eliminandolos

Lo que yo e intentado:

```
array_splice($productos,0,10);
```

esto me funciona porque me elimina apartir de la 10 pero me asigna nuevos indices correlativos y con esto yo pierdo el indice del array...

Comment: Y cual seria el problema????

Comment: Andre, como sugerencias, edita la pregunta con algún código que estés probando y no te da los resultados esperados o te da errores. No está bien visto que los demás hagan el trabajo por uno.

Comment: Por otra parte, si no sabes cómo afrontarlo, en la docu de PHP está [esta función, array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-slice.php). [O for](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.for.php), o [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) con [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php). Hay varias formas de hacer lo que quieres. Prueba las distintas opciones y si te dan errores edita la pregunta.

Comment: Explica por qué en tu código se generan datos que luego será desechados. No parece ser una buena práctica y quizá convenga resolver este problema en la raíz.

Comment: @A.Cedano claro pero por ejemplo lo que hago es buscar todos mis registros de ventas y con un while recorrer cada uno e ir sumandolo al indice que contenga el id_producto luego de esto ya tengo armado todos mis productos con su respectiva cantidad de ventas pero yo solo necesito los 10 primeros para poder crear un top 10 de productos mas vendidos.
Yo se que puedo hacer un SUM() mysql pero necesiro recorrer todos estos campos porque ahy productos que los e vendido a precios diferentes siendo el mismo y bueno tambien quiero aislar eso

Comment: Es que SQL tiene formas de consultar a los datos para que te traigan **exactamente aquello que necesitas**. Intuí desde un principio que había aquí una mala práctica y tu comentario me lo confirma. Te aconsejo que no plantees la solución al  problema de este modo, no tiene sentido traer datos para luego desechar una parte de ellos, cuando puedes obtener justo aquello que necesitas. Aunque en principio funcione, esto puede traerte serios problemas a posteriori, en la medida en que la BD o los usuarios crezcan.

Comment: ¿Y con `array_chunk($productos, 10, true)[0]`?... eso quizas no funcione, pero esto quizas si:  `$partes = array_chunk($productos, 10, true); var_dump($partes[0]);`

Comment: Escribiendo tu consulta SQL de este modo, obtendrás solamente 10 registros, que es lo que necesitas: `SELECT * FROM tuTabla LIMIT 10;` Si requieres otros criterios, como filtrar por el valor de una columna, puedes usar  `WHERE`, y si requieres ordenar usas `ORDER BY` y si requieres sumar usas `SUM`, etc. Los SGBD son herramientas completas y poderosas para hacer casi cualquier cosa mediante consultas SQL. Lo único que justificaría traer registros para descartar una parte de ellos en esta parte de tu código, es que los otros registros (descartados aquí) se usen de algún modo para otra cosa.

Comment: No tiene sentido traerte 20 registros para eliminar 10, en ese caso realiza el filtrado en SQL trayendo solo los 10 primeros registros con un `LIMIT 10`. Cuáles serán esos 10 registros? los que establezcas en el `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener los 10 primeros elementos del array con `array_chunk()` de este modo:

```
$productos = array_chunk($productos,10,true)[0]);
```

Segun la descripción de la [página de array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-chunk.php) en php.net:

> array_chunk(array $array, int $size, bool $preserve_keys
> = false): array
>
> Divide un array en arrays con elementos del tamaño definido en size.
> El último fragmento puede contener menos elementos que size.

Como solo te interesa **el primer array de 10 elementos** que `array_chunk()` divide, le ponemos un **[0]** al final de la función para capturarlo.

El tercer parámetro de `array_chunk()` lo establecemos en *true* para **preservar los índices**.

Comment: el probema viene del planteamiento, si bien esta seria una solucion, arreglar algo mal planteado, solo resulta en algo mal planteado y parchado... hay que ir al origen, en este caso es la consulta mysql que NO esta optimizada

Comment: @JhonSilver si bien estoy de acuerdo en que el planteamiento de la pregunta no es correcto, no creo que las respuestas deban ser sobre la consulta a la base de datos. Imaginemos por un momento una persona buscando información sobre como eliminar elementos de un array y se encuentra que las respuestas son sobre sql... Entiendo que se puede sugerir ese tema, y habría que tratarlo en una nueva pregunta, con respuestas que tengan relación directa con la pregunta. La respuesta de forma literal, responde a la pregunta planteada.

Comment: @JhonSilver Si estamos ante un caso de [problema XY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY) el tiempo lo dirá. De momento tan solo me he planteado como hacerlo basándome en lo que el OP requiere en este caso.  Si nos aporta más información sobre como hace el recorrido con el while y efectua esas sumas quizás podremos aportarle la solución mediante consulta SQL con LIMIT 10 y seguramente con algun JOIN entre tablas.  Por cierto, me gusta más la respuesta aportada por OscarR, seguramente es más rapida (antes de dar esta respuesta me habia mirado al array_slice pero quizas en diagonal).

Answer (score 1):

Sobre el funcionamiento de [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-slice.php), la documentación describe los parámetros que le puedes pasar:

```
array_slice(
    array $array,
    int $offset,
    int $length = null,
    bool $preserve_keys = false
): array
```

Entre ellos está:

> **preserve_keys**
> Observe que array_slice() reordenará y reinicializará los índices numéricos del array de forma predeterminada. Se puede cambiar esta comportamiento estableciendo el parámetro preserve_keys a true.

Supongamos que tenemos lo siguiente `var_dump($array);`:

```
array (size=12)
  1 => string 'Uno'
  3 => string 'Tres'
  16 => string 'Dieciséis'
  4 => string 'Cuatro'
  28 => string 'Veintiocho'
  7 => string 'Siete'
  14 => string 'Catorce'
  19 => string 'Diecinueve'
  21 => string 'Veintiuno'
  8 => string 'Ocho'
  10 => string 'Diez'
  12 => string 'Doce'
```

Si pasamos esos valores por `var_dump(array_slice($array, 0, 10))` obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
array (size=10)
  0 => string 'Uno'
  1 => string 'Tres'
  2 => string 'Dieciséis'
  3 => string 'Cuatro'
  4 => string 'Veintiocho'
  5 => string 'Siete'
  6 => string 'Catorce'
  7 => string 'Diecinueve'
  8 => string 'Veintiuno'
  9 => string 'Ocho'
```

Pero si usamos el último parámetro `$preserve_keys = true`  `var_dump(array_slice($array, 0, 10, true))` obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
array (size=10)
  1 => string 'Uno'
  3 => string 'Tres'
  16 => string 'Dieciséis'
  4 => string 'Cuatro'
  28 => string 'Veintiocho'
  7 => string 'Siete'
  14 => string 'Catorce'
  19 => string 'Diecinueve'
  21 => string 'Veintiuno'
  8 => string 'Ocho'
```

En resumen, a la pregunta original **eliminar ultimos registros de array** con el contexto **Tengo un array con mas de 20 elementos y yo solo deseo los 10 primeros**.

Una posible respuesta que lo resuelve en una sola línea podría ser:

```
$result = array_slice($array, 0, 10, true);
```

Comment: Otra cosa es si el planteamiento que se está realizando es el correcto. Lo ideal es traer solo lo necesario desde la base de datos, si lo permite. Si no, pues están las alternativas.

Answer (score 0):

Existe la opción de eliminar .unset(), que te permite eliminar los elementos que tu quieras, de una manera más exacta(debes saber bien las posiciones que quieres eliminar).

Un ejemplo :

```
$numeros = array(1,2,3,4,5,6); 
var_export ($numeros);
```

```
unset($numeros[2]);
   var_export ($numeros);
```

```
unset($numeros[0],$numeros[1]);
          var_export ($numeros1);
```

**En tu caso, deberías usar un bucle(por ejemplo un for):**

```
 $array_lenght = count($productos);
          for($i = 10; $i<$array_lenght;i++){
          unset($productos[$i]);
}
```

Al ser un array asociativo, debes cambiar el bucle de arriba, por algo que se ajuste a tu ejemplo(Usa un bucle forEach)

tambien puedes utilizar [array_slice()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-slice.php)

```
$salida = array_slice($numeros, 0 ,4);
```